# Why is the SML compiler telling me it is returning an int list

Tags: sml, sudoku

I am making a sudoku solver and I am wondering why the sml compiler is saying:

```
expression: int * int -> int -> int list list list
result type: int * int -> int -> int list
```

in the declaration

```
val moveandsolve = (fn arg => (fn pat => exp))
```

I am trying to return a list of lists of lists(list of boards) but it is telling me that it is returning an int list? Am I not using the mutual recursion correctly?

```
fun solve board =
    let fun fillInAndSolve (board, (row, col)) entry=
        let val newbrd1 = fillin (board,(row,col),entry)
        in 
            if(contradictionDetected newbrd1) = true
            then 
                []
            else 
                let val newbrd2 = 
                    forces newbrd1
                in 
                    if(contradictionDetected newbrd2) = true
                    then
                        []
                    else
                        if (hasEmptyPos newbrd2) = false
                        then
                            newbrd2
                        else
                            List.map (moveandsolve board (findFirstBlank newbrd2))
                                     (generateListOfLegals(newbrd2,findFirstBlank newbrd2))
                end
        end

    in List.map (fillInAndSolve(board, findFirstBlank board))
                (generateListOfLegals(board, findFirstBlank(board)))
    end

and moveandsolve board (row, col) label =
    solve (fillin(board, (row,col), label ));
```

Comment: In your innermost conditional, `newbrd2` doesn't look much like a list of lists of lists.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I not using the mutual recursion correctly?

No.

Although, you are not specifying *what* function that has this type (you supply multiple), and you leave out parts: `generateListOfLegals`, `contradictionDetected`, `forces`, `hasEmptyPos`, `fillin`, `findFirstBlank`, rendering the program unable to compile. Assuming they all exist and add no constraints to the type inference, you would get the following type error:

```
! solve (fillin(board, (row,col), label ));<EOF>
! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
! Type clash: expression of type
! 'a list list
! cannot have type
! 'a
! because of circularity
```

Circularity is a conflict when resolving types. A simpler example could be this function:

```
fun f x = f [x];
```

If it worked, then `f x = f [x] = f [[x]] = f [[[x]]] = ...`, which would lead to recursion until running out of memory. But it doesn't get past type-checking: If the input type is *'a*, then the output type must be *'a list*. But then the input type must be *'a list*, and the output type *'a list list*, and so on:

```
! Type clash: expression of type
! 'a list
! cannot have type
! 'a
! because of circularity
```

Thus, your function appears to break down input *'a list list*s into *'a*s and feed them to itself (indirectly) as input. **So:** Try and look at what your function returns in all cases and see if those expressions all have the same type. I suspect that maybe `forces newbrd1` does not have the proper return type, but this is purely guesswork.